# how to Display Image on Modal HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

could anyone help me how to show modal image by click url image,
this bellow my code

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('ok');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = myImg.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = myImg.value;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="home.gif" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200" display="none">
<div id="ok" style="width: 50px; height: 30px; background-color: red">Click</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

in the page, I want to show only image link url, without **`<img id = "myImg" src="url"/>`** tag. and whenever i click the link url the image modal will be show

Comment: I think you are trying to create a lightbox? Take a look into this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Comment: no, i dnt it, it just like url and when I click the url, image showed in modal the simple question

Comment: You don't have a variable `myImg` but you are using it in your javascript like a var. Add `var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');`

Comment: can u please provide us with a code that matches your request. In your example your are doing exactly what you say, you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're looking for this:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('ok');
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg').src;
var myImgAlt = document.getElementById('myImg').alt;
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = myImg;
    document.getElementById('img01').style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById('img01').style.height = "200px";
    captionText.innerHTML = myImgAlt;
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2012/11/152964589-welcome-home-new-cat-632x475.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200" display="none">
        <div id = "ok" style="width: 50px; height: 30px; background-color: red">Click</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```